# sqlplus command not found on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line

I have completely installed Oracle 10g Xe on Ubuntu 14.04, configured it and in that session I have successfully created some tables in the database.

I closed the terminal and after some time I opened it again and wrote the  command `sqlplus`.
It shows `sqlplus: command not found`.

What might be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Did anything you do in the previous session where you configured sqlplus involve environment variables? (commands like `something=anything else`)

Comment: No,I have not use any commands like that.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `$PATH` variable. Add `$ORACLE_HOME/bin` to it. Or wherever the Xe places its binaries.

Comment: So it means Oracle has to be configured again. What is the command to re-configure Oracle ?  Can it be done ?

Comment: You just need to setup your shell environment variables. Based on experience with standard and enterprise, there should be some env script provided. Try looking for a file named `*oraenv*`.